# How can I push website from server to client using wifi connection?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to make an application that can push ads (website) to client..

Here is the case :
Client try to connect to internet via wifi. 
Once the client is connected, server send a website address to client, and a popup (website sent by server) will appear in the client's computer in default browser.

I can list all IP connected to server, but i don't know how to push the website to client

Thanks

Here is the code to list all IP connected to server : (import System.Net library)

```
        String strHostName = "";
        if(args == null || args.Length == 0){
            strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            MessageBox.Show("Local Machine's Host Name: " + strHostName);
        }else{
            strHostName = args[0];
        }

        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        int i = 0;
        while(i< addr.Length){
            MessageBox.Show("IP Address "+i+": "+addr[i].ToString());
            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: ups..sorry, i forgot to place '?' mark :p

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you maybe want to create some form of a Captive Portal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Captive Portals are the type of site you see when you connect to a wifi network and it asks for payment or some other form of authentication regardless of what site you attempt to navigate to.

If your intent it to actually serve the user agent's requested page in addition to serving them a popup ad, you would need to intercept this request, and insert some javascript into the page that would trigger the popup, and return this modified markup to the user agent.

Comment: yups, that's what i intent to do..And how to intercept the request? Would you please write the code, or do you have website reference to do this?

Comment: You will want to create / modify a proxy server.  Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server for details on the concept and example proxy servers at the end of article (some of them are open source so you could add your desired functionality).

Comment: but, the client must set the proxy to the server right? What I want is when the client connect through wifi, the server interrupt the request, and return the response plus the ads, without setting the proxy server manually from every client

Comment: This proxy would be setup on the server side to route all traffic through it by default.  You are correct that users can configure their own proxy, but yours would be 'hard coded' so to speak.